# How to toggle "programmer mode" and scientific mode of the Calculator?

Tags: 8.0

Something kinda weird happened, the calculator got stuck in a "programmer mode" (hex digits in buttons etc), which I've never seen before, when I turn it to landscape. And now I can't seem to switch it of for "normal" scientific mode.

I've got a feeling this *has* to be something really simple, but I just haven't managed to do the right thing. Quitting the calc and restarting it won't help, etc. So what to do?

Comment: I think you best add a screenshot of what you are seeing

Comment: @akid Got an answer, but also found [this wpcentral forum post](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-apps/238700-wp8-standard-calculator-scientific-extended-scientific-modes.html) which shows the 3 modes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are actually 2 landscape modes depending on which way you turn the device, you'll get a different mode. Turning the phone 90 degrees counterclockwise (bottom of phone in your right hand) will put it into regular scientific mode. Turning the phone 90 degrees clockwise (bottom of the phone in your left hand) will put it into programmer mode.

[image: Standard Calculator]
[image: Scientific Calculator]
[image: Programmer Calculator]

Comment: Very cool! Never noticed this before. But now I'm slightly disappointed that turning the phone upside down doesn't put it into a fourth mode (say, statistics).

Answer (score 3):

The calculator app is designed to always be scientific or programmer mode in the landscape orientations, and a standard calculator for portrait mode. If you're stuck in one mode, rotate the device so it landscape the other way (flip it upside down). By doing this, they are taking advantage of the horizontal and vertical layouts in a natural way, while allowing for ease of use while transitioning between the two modes.

Comment: I simply love how the calculator changes the mode, just by rotating my device :)

Comment: @hyde Thanks for pointing out my omission! I've updated.